# How to Find the difference in time between the "dirty' status bed and "Completed" Status bed in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to Find the difference in time between the "dirty' status bed and "Completed" Status bed in sql. Lets say for example here is the data

```
ID       Cleaning Stage    Event Time
======   ==============    ==============   
790248   Dirty             1/2/2019  5:36 PM
790248   Assigned          1/2/2019  5:58 PM
790248   On Hold           1/2/2019  5:58 PM
790248   Assigned          1/2/2019  6:21 PM
790248   In Progress       1/2/2019  6:52 PM
790248   Completed         1/2/2019  7:59 PM
```

like this it goes on for all beds . So I want to calculate the cleaning time for each bed by subtracting the time between dirty and completed Above I have just one bed as an example. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the two statuses using conditional aggregation:

```
select id, min(case when stage = 'Dirty' then time end) as dirty_time,
       max(case when stage = 'Completed' then time end) as completed_time
from t
group by id;
```

You can then use `timestampdiff()` to subtract these and get the time you want in the units you want.